# htaccess rewrite engine doesnt redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello this is my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z]*$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/home$ /index.php?u=$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/blog$ /blog.php?u=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/contact$ /contact.php?u=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/portfolio$ /portfolio.php?u=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/page_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  /page.php?id=$2&u=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/post_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /post.php?id=$2&u=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/blog_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /blog.php?id=$2&u=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/project_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /project.php?id=$2&u=$1 [L]
```

all the lines work besides the first one, I think I might need to use conditions?
here is what im trying to do if someone goes to site.com/john for example they will be sent to `/index.php?a=profile&u=$1` which is the profile for the username=john in this case. but what happens is it sends me back to index.php

Comment: well now what happened is ... its skipping the other lines. so it redirects to /a=profile&u=$1 BUT the other directives are being ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should remove `[L]`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1
```

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In
>   most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules
>   will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or
>   the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current
>   rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

Comment: that skips the other directives under that line.